# ¿Cómo puedo atender varios TcpClient sin mantener un Thread para cada uno?

Tags: .net, hilos, socket, vb

Tengo una aplicación con numerosas conexiones con sockets tcpClient, y aunque aparentemente funciona, creo que no es la manera en que debería hacerse.

Ahora mismo para cada conexión creo un Thread propio para cada tcpClient, en el que realizo la conexión, recibo los datos y los proceso y devuelvo según corresponda. Los Threads son todos de segundo plano y están preparados para hacerlos terminar de forma natural en cualquier momento. No se bloquean con los métodos .Connect ni .Read porque hago comprobaciones previas, aunque sí tengo un Thread.Sleep(1000) para cuando no tengo datos que leer. Todos los Threads están vivos durante toda la vida del programa, y si alguno termina tengo un Form.Timer que lo vuelve a arrancar.

He leído mucho sobre Threads, ThreadPool, BackgroundWorker, Task(TPL) y Async/Await, pero no sé como encarar esto de otra manera. ThreadPool y BackgroundWorker se supone que están obsoletos desde la llegada de Task(TPL). Thread en algunos sitios aconsejan usarlo para procesos que duran en marcha toda la vida de la aplicación, pero en otros desaconsejan su uso totalmente. Task(TPL) se aconseja para tareas cortas...

La información que encuentro sobre los métodos .BeginConnect del tcpClient y .BeginRead del NetworkStream me parece muy escasa y superficial y no soy capaz de hacer que funcione como los Threads que ya tengo.

¿Cómo puedo encarar un programa que tiene que atender y procesar peticiones de multitud de clientes?

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y seguramente la cerraran. Pero no entiendo porque una app con winforms tendria muchos clientes!. Deberias hacer un servicio que tome las peticiones y le devuelva la respuesta al cliente (winforms)